# makefile: link to a library if it installed. How to? and how to disable?

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, ld, rocksdb

I am building rocksdb

seem rocksdb's makefile will detect my system's compression library(snappy, libz), if installed rocksdb will link to it.

I am interested in how rocksdb do that. The makefile is so complicate and I can't find which part do the job.

I hope to prevent this action, I hope rocksdb only link snappy, not zlib which download in my linux machine.

makefile:https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/main/Makefile

Comment: Looks like it doesn't use the system version of snappy and libz at all, but instead downloads the sources and builds them as part of the rocksdb build process: https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/main/Makefile#L2155-L2228

Comment: What a horrible makefile! It's trying to do double-duty as a configuration script as well (with some success, I'm sure), which would be better separated into its own script.  But on the other hand, it sort of is, because there's a whole directory full of build-support scripts, many of which support primarily the system-configuration aspect, rather than the build proper.  These are involved, at least in some cases, in choosing the appropriate build flags for the compression libraries.

Comment: Maybe try a run as follows: `make JAVA_STATIC_FLAGS="-DBZIP2 -DSNAPPY -DLZ4 -DZSTD" JAVA_COMPRESSIONS = "libbz2.a libsnappy.a liblz4.a libzstd.a"` as a test to take zlib out of the build?

Answer (score 0):

Thank to @John Bollinger 's comment.

This makefile work as configuration script generates the `make_config.mk` file, and the `PLATFORM_LDFLAGS` in `make_config.mk` indicates the library that the system has.

[build_detect_platform](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/be09943fb58a2dd3f70e6e30781ebfa3fcbcb8fa/build_tools/build_detect_platform) is responsible for generating `make_config.mk`. It work like this

```bash
if ! test $ROCKSDB_DISABLE_SNAPPY; then
  # Test whether Snappy library is installed
  # http://code.google.com/p/snappy/
  $CXX $PLATFORM_CXXFLAGS -x c++ - -o test.o 2>/dev/null  <<EOF
  #include <snappy.h>
  int main() {}
EOF
  if [ "$?" = 0 ]; then
    COMMON_FLAGS="$COMMON_FLAGS -DSNAPPY"
    PLATFORM_LDFLAGS="$PLATFORM_LDFLAGS -lsnappy"
    JAVA_LDFLAGS="$JAVA_LDFLAGS -lsnappy"
  fi
fi
```

so I can set `ROCKSDB_DISABLE_ZLIB` to prevent link to zlib